# Spring Security 6 OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I don't understand why Spring Security Logout Filter stand before any authentication filter. When I try to peform logout in Spring Boot linked to OIDC provider - via adding logoutSucceshandler customization behaviour - OIDC provider end session endpoint will be never invoked because of Authentication object always be null.

Part of code related to logout:

```
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .logout(logout->logout
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .clearAuthentication(true)
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler())
                )
        ;
        return http.build();
    }


    private LogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler() {
        OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler =
                new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(this.clientRegistrationRepository);
        oidcLogoutSuccessHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("{baseUrl}");
        return oidcLogoutSuccessHandler;
    }
```

Inteleji Idea screenshot during debug of logout :

[image]

**Please anyone help**

Comment: What is your reason for not implementing OIDC logout as defined in the official documentation?

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thanks for the answer. I check https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-oidc-logout . As i see it looks almost like mine. Core problem is it is no Authentication object formed so - determineTargetUrl method section where endSession End point calling start skips.

Comment: Yes, ”almost”, you have defined that your application is stateless, but still you want to delete a stateful cookie?

Comment: @Toerktumlare You are right . I remove all related code lines to session management .Now it exactly looks like in documentation. But problem still appear

Comment: OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler is called when logout was ... successful. If the user does not have a valid (authorized) session, or if the logout request is malformed, logout won't be successful and the success handler will never be called. So, you should probably start by understanding why the logout is not successful (and we have not enough elements to figure this out)

Comment: @ch4mp I understand my mistake.My security filter chain bean designed incorrect.I have only one which contains .oath2Login().oath2ResourceServer(),oath2Client.As I understand now it should be breaked in 2 separate SecurityFilterChain beans.1-st security filter chain set up for resource server behaviour,2-nd security filter chain set up oath2Login - because my application is - Spring Boot 2 OAuth Client and Resourceserver in the same context